# Gradle build script not able to download Nexus artifact through HTTP proxy - HTTP 503 error recieved

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I have below repositories in my build script

```
repositories {
    mavenRepo url: "http://ip:port/artifactory/plugins-release",
           artifactUrls: ["file://${System.properties['user.home']}/.m2/repository/"]
    mavenRepo url: "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"
    mavenRepo url: "http://mvnCompanyPortal/nexus/content/repositories/releases"
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Which actually download these dependencies through HTTP proxy. If I run:

```
gradle build proxyHost port
```

I got:

```
HTTP 503 error when downloading dependency from that repository.
```

If I remove the proxy, it works fine but artifacts from other repositories fail to be downloaded.

How to tell Gradle to not to use Http proxy for local repository but use for remote.

Any example would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup non proxy hosts.

```
$ gradle <task> -Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy port> -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

In the above example *.nonproxyrepos.com means all subdomain of nonproxyrepos.com will be excluded from proxy also localhost.

Also these configuration can be kept in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` so you don't need to type proxy setting every time check 20.2. Accessing the web via a proxy section in [Chapter 20. The Build Environment](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Karthikeyan.